# Is there a way to use Ubuntu in WSL2 as a portable program that can be written to a flash drive and run on different computers?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker

I moved Ubuntu to drive D (flash drive) with these commands:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl --export Ubuntu D:\WSL\UbuntuBackup.tar 
wsl --unregister Ubuntu 
wsl --import Ubuntu D:\WSL\ D:\WSL\UbuntuBackup.tar --version 2
```

I inserted the flash drive into my laptop, but my Ubuntu is not there. It needs to be imported as in the last command:

```
wsl --import Ubuntu D:\WSL\ D:\WSL\UbuntuBackup.tar --version 2
```

After working on my laptop, I need to export my Ubuntu again and then import on my PC. It is very uncomfortable. I wish I didn't have to do this. I just want to plug in the flash drive and work. I have already seen similar questions on this site, but they were several years ago. Is this possible now?